# Erro python locale

Tags: python, pandas

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil.1252")
data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/t714591/Videos/bancos/base.xlsx')

data["Valor"] = locale.currency(data["Valor"], grouping=True, symbol=None)
```

Estou com esse erro quando eu uso o `locale` pra converter o número em PT-BR:

```
"{0}".format(str(converter)))
```

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to

Comment: Isso porque você está passando uma série do pandas, mas a função espera um número. Se quiser formatar todos os valores, veja como mapea-los

Comment: Entendi e como posso fazer pra alterar cada um ?

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver usando lambda:

```
data["Valor"] = data.Valor.apply(lambda x: locale.currency(x, grouping=True, symbol=None))
```